# Can someone explain how to filter preg_match php

Tags: php

Okay so I am trying to use `preg_match()` in php and I would like to only filter letters and white space. But I dont understand the filtering part.
So this is what I have. So this would echo false currently but how would I allow spaces and capital letters?

```
$usertest = "username is Cheese";

if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $usertest)) {
    echo 'TRUE';
} else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

Comment: I can always recommend to use https://regex101.com if you write a regex. Also look at the quick reference at the bottom right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part between the slashs (`/`) is a marker that there is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `[]` means here is a single char. The `a-z` means it can be any char between a and z: so the full lowercase alphabet. In the end that will match every any string which will contain a little letter.

If you will really limit the input to lower case letters and spaces try this expression here:

```
/^[a-z ]+$/
```

The `^` means that is the start of the string while `$` marks the end. The `+` sign is a modifier that the letter before should be there at least one time.

Comment: so I dont really need the `/` only [a-z]?

Comment: @Ash that slashes are required in PHP to let the function know that you entered a regular expression.